# Use trained model layer in creating another model in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I created a model in Keras like below:

```
    m = Sequential()
    m.add(Dense(912, activation='relu', input_shape=(943, 1)))
    m.add(Dense(728, activation='relu'))
    m.add(Dense(528, activation='relu'))
    m.add(Flatten())
    m.add(Dense(500, activation='relu', name="bottleneck"))
    m.add(Dense(528, activation='relu'))
    m.add(Dense(728, activation='relu'))
    m.add(Dense(943, activation='linear'))

    m.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='SGD')
    m.summary()
```

Now I want to take `bottleneck` layer and add in my below creating network:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(930, activation='relu', input_shape=(943, 1)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(m.get_layer('bottleneck'))
    model.add(m.get_layer('bottleneck'))
    model.add(m.get_layer('bottleneck'))
    model.add(m.get_layer('bottleneck'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='linear'))
```

but after training model `m`, raise an error when to starting error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer bottleneck: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 497904 but got shape (None, 876990)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is trying to tell you that the shape of your input to the 'bottleneck' layer is different in the second model compared to the first.

In order to re-use a layer you need to match up the number of inputs to that layer. In your case the first model has 497904 inputs to this layer but you are trying to use it in your next model with an input layer with 876990 inputs.

I suspect you want something more like this (note, I have flattened immediately in each case so we can keep a better grip on the # of inputs at each layer):

```
m = Sequential()
m.add(Flatten(input_shape=(943, 1)))
m.add(Dense(912, activation='relu'))
m.add(Dense(728, activation='relu'))
m.add(Dense(528, activation='relu'))
m.add(Dense(500, activation='relu', name="bottleneck"))
m.add(Dense(528, activation='relu'))
m.add(Dense(728, activation='relu'))
m.add(Dense(943, activation='linear'))

m.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='SGD')
m.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 943)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 912)               860928    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 728)               664664    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 528)               384912    
_________________________________________________________________
bottleneck (Dense)           (None, 500)               264500    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 528)               264528    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 728)               385112    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 943)               687447    
=================================================================
Total params: 3,512,091
Trainable params: 3,512,091
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And note that the INPUT to our bottleneck layer has shape `(None,528)`. So now, in the second model we can do:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(930, activation='relu', input_shape=(943, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(528, activation='relu'))
model.add(m.get_layer('bottleneck'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='linear'))
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 943, 930)          1860      
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 876990)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 528)               463051248 
_________________________________________________________________
bottleneck (Dense)           (None, 500)               264500    
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_4 (Flatten)          (None, 500)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 100)               50100     
=================================================================
Total params: 463,367,708
Trainable params: 463,367,708
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Are you sure? Im on mobile now or I'd test again but I tested it before posting. Did you change both models as above??

Comment: If not, I'll have another look when I get home. :-)

Comment: No, I don't change it, I waiting for your response.

Comment: The code seems fine to me - here it is running ok in a colab environment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wNqV99Rrx8RGdzk6PhWOzX13HvzBPv90 Perhaps retry another copy and paste from my answer? I changed both models. If you still can't get it working try reproducing your error in a new colab notebook and post the link & I'll have a look